# grails custom GORM dialect prevent 'grails shell' to work - classpath mystery

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

i'm using Grails 2.3.11.

My domain classes use UUIDs as identifiers stored as binary(16) in MySQL. I have used a very simple custom dialect for Hibernate, and placed it in src/java:

```
class CustomMysqlDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
  public CustomMysqlDialect() {
    super();
    registerColumnType(Types.BINARY,"binary(16)");
  }
}
```

Then in domain classes i can just use

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: 'uuid2',sqlType:'BINARY(16)'
...
}
```

All this work fine, except the `grails shell` command:

```
± |binary-uuid ✗| → grails shell
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Error Error executing script Shell: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean 
property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate dialect class (Use --stacktrace to see 
the full trace)
```

Just like the classes in src/java wouldn't get added to the classpath.

The grails console works just fine, and i can easily query/create/update my domain classes, but i really miss the interactivity of the shell...

I tried to put the class in grails-app/utils as well, but it doesn't change anything...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked fine for me. Does it help if you run `grails clean` and `grails compile` before starting the shell? Also try adding `--verbose --stacktrace` to the `compile` and `shell` commands - you might be missing a warning or error message:

```
$ grails clean
$ grails compile --verbose --stacktrace
$ grails shell --verbose --stacktrace
```

Note that `grails-app/utils` is misleadingly named. It's not for utility classes, it's for Codecs. Put all Groovy and Java code that not a grails-app artifact (controller, service, codec, etc.) in `src/groovy` and `src/java`.

Comment: Thanks @Burt ! 

I was carried away by groovy's default to make classes public, and forgot to make this **java** class public !

Your tip helped find out the root cause of the exception:

    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory can not access a member of class CustomMysqlDialect with modifiers ""
         at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:65) ...org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.constructDialect(DialectFactory.java:156)
 ... 371 more

Comment: now do you have an idea why the `run-app` script will happily work with the original class, while `shell` won't work ?